# Drupal 8 : Multiple content approval within group

Tags: drupal-8

I am using Drupal group module and content moderation from core which has draft, review and publish state for node. 
Now my requirement is, I need an option to have node publish for same content based on group.
Example:
 -> I have group A and Group B
 -> I create node "node one" of type page under group A.
 -> "node one" gets reviewed and published by approver. And Hence "node one" is now visible for group A members.

-> Now, In Group B, I create the same "node one" from existing content.

Since "node one" is already published, it will not go through the workflow state of review, publish again .
But I have a requirement that, when already published node is added in other group ( in this case, it is group B ), then approver should get mail to review this node and publish/reject.

Note that client is not ready to create new node under each group. They want to use the existing nodes. 
Any solution or suggestions here please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) (og) module or [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.

Comment: Yes, we are using group module and content moderation from core.